# Typescript noob question about having an parameter object with default props in class constructor

Tags: typescript, dry

I have a javascript class that I want to rewrite to TS:

```js
class A {
  constructor({foo = 'foo', bar = 123, baz = true} = {}) {
    this.foo = foo
    this.bar = bar
    this.baz = baz
  }
}
```

What that I currently wrote on TS:

```js
interface AProps {
  foo: string,
  bar: number,
  baz: boolean,
}

class A {
  foo: string
  bar: number
  baz: boolean

  constructor({foo = 'foo', bar = 123, baz = true}: Partial<AProps> = {}) {
    this.foo = foo
    this.bar = bar
    this.baz = baz
  }
}
```

As you can see, typescript has 3 times more code, how to do this more compact?
As I know, almost any code duplication is anti-pattern so there must be the way to tell typescript that I want all fields in class from that interface.

Comment: Your JS version is not syntactically correct, `constructor({foo= 'foo', bar= 123, baz= true} = {}) {` is the way to go

Comment: @Lesiak thanks, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify AProps interface to hint type of the constructor, it will be inferred correctly.

```
class A {
  foo: string
  bar: number
  baz: boolean

  constructor({foo = 'foo', bar = 123, baz = true} = {}) {
    this.foo = foo
    this.bar = bar
    this.baz = baz
  }
}
```

Constructor has type:

```
constructor A({ foo, bar, baz }?: {
    foo?: string | undefined;
    bar?: number | undefined;
    baz?: boolean | undefined;
}): A
```

`const a = new A({x: 1});` fails to compile with a message

> ```
> Argument of type '{ x: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo?: string | undefined; bar?: number | undefined; baz?: boolean | undefined; }'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type '{ foo?: string | undefined; bar?: number | undefined; baz?: boolean | undefined; }'.(2345)
> ```

**With original code**

constructor has type:

```
constructor A({ foo, bar, baz }?: Partial<AProps>): A
```

`const a = new A({x: 1});` fails to compile with a message

> ```
> Argument of type '{ x: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<AProps>'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type 'Partial<AProps>'.(2345)
> ```